# Java: Can't figure out how to use class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() so it works when i build artifacts

Tags: java, classloader

I have been tasked with developing a discord bot for a friend of mine and need to load some strings from a file. Now, to make this work when i export the project into a jar, someone told me to use class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()

After fiddling around for 2 hours, reading documentation and asking again, i got it to work in intelliJ. It still does not work when i build the project though.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vohic.png)
My Code:

```
static final ArrayList<String> QUOTES = new ArrayList<>();

public static void loadArray() {
    try{
        //File fin = new File("src/main/java/com/github/MarvelousAdain/Quotes");
        //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fin);
        System.out.println("Called loadArray Method");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Utilities.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Quotes")));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            QUOTES.add(line);
        }
        System.out.println("Quotes loaded, no Problem.");
        br.close();
    }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

If i try running my code in the jar, this throws a NullPointerException.

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.github.MarvelousAdain.Utilities.loadArray(Utilities.java:31)
    at com.github.MarvelousAdain.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the file actually just called `Quotes`? And is it not inside any packages?

Comment: It is just called Quotes, yes. I tried moving the files to a different location within a package, but didn't get it to work, no matter what path i entered.

Comment: Just to clarify: is it `Quotes` or something like a `Quotes.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

Is the tool that creates the jar including the resource?

You can check with

```
jar tf myjar.jar
```

Or indeed, your favourite zip tool.

Peculiarly `getResourceAsStream()` returns `null` instead of throwing some kind of `IOException` like a normal API would.

Also note that `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` will take the name relative to the classpath, but `Class.getResourceAsStream` will modify the path using the name of the package of the specified class (i.e. in the same "directory" as the `.class` file).

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: It seems that it didn't include it.

Comment: @MarvelousAdain Then you'll need to make sure that it does.

Answer (score 0):

So, this might be more of a work around, but it was the only way i got it to work right now. If someone has a better idea, which i'm sure someone has, then i'd still like to hear it.

I built the jar, opened it with winrar and put the 3 files that i want to read in there. It worked. If i put them in the same place within the IDE, it did not. I have no idea how/why this is the case, but for now this works for me. I'll update this if i find something better!